# Which cross platform app building tool should I use?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform, mosync

I need to build an app that works on `IPhone`, `Android` and `Blackberry` and it involves sending *SMS*'s (or opening the native SMS service with preloaded contacts and message), access to contacts and push notifications.

The app is simple to build but I have never built an app before and that's why I am looking into cross platform tools. I am currently using Sencha touch for the UI and I've looked into `Phonegap` and `Mosync`.

`Phonegap` doesn't support push notifications and sending *SMS*. Getting contacts in `Mosync` using PIM is slow and I haven't programmed in c/c++. `Phonegap` does have plugins but they are different plugins for `Android`, `iOS` and `Blackberry` which defeats the point of a cross platform app.

So I am confused how to go about building this app and any suggestions for other tools or general recommendations would help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Phonegap does have plugins but they are different plugins for Android, iOS and blackberry which defeats the point of a cross platform app

No, it does not. It means that ~90% of your app might work without modification, and ~10% would have to be tailored per-platform. Most developers would be rather happy with that.

A perfectly 100% cross-platform app is a nice objective, just as living forever is a nice objective. However, like living forever, a perfectly 100% cross-platform app is not especially common.

Comment: Yes, the differences between Android and iOS are so vast, it is not possible nor practical to have code that is 100% cross platform.  If you did, you would certainly be missing some features from both sides in an effort to only include stuff that can be deployed on both.  Also living forever is more than just not common, it is impossible :P.

Comment: Thanks, your ~90% and ~10% point makes sense to me. But with this project phonegap will only be useful for getting contacts. So its more of a case that 33% will work without modification and 77% will have to be modified (ignoring the UI as that's done in sencha touch). Would it be still worth it using phonegap or should I research into other tools?

Comment: @user972616: "ignoring the UI as that's done in sencha touch" -- that should be a substantial part of your app and is part of my 90/10 estimation. "Would it be still worth it using phonegap or should I research into other tools?" -- you will not find anything that gets you substantially closer, in all likelihood. So, it's a question of how much time you want to spend on research versus actually building the app.

Comment: Ya probably quicker just to start building. Thanks for the insight.